# Scrollview is not scrolling using autolayout though I have added proper constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have got a layout in following form

I have got the views in following hierarchies.

```
  ---View
    -------TopView
    ---------Label
  --Scrollview
  ---------ContentView
  ----Buton
```

The content view has got the constraing attributes as in the following picture,

[image]

The problem is that scrollview is not getting scrolled.
Am i missing any layout constraints from being set? scroll view is of  width 374 and height 534. Contentview is of  width 334 and height 494

Comment: is your content view is fixed height?  bigger enough to scroll ?

Comment: scroll view is of  width 374 and height 534. Contentview is of  width 334 and height 494

Comment: if I use self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 700); within viewDidLayoutSubviews, its getting scrolled but is it possible to mention this from storyboard?

Comment: if you dealing with constraints you not need to set content size manually , if your content view is bigger then scroll view it will start scrolling automatically

Comment: I have made the size of content view to be more than that of scrollview from interface builder but still it is not scrolling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you try to add the scroll view on something like submit application/ form then remember these steps:

1. On base view add a scroll view with frame exactly equal to base view
2. add top left bottom and right constrain (should be 0 each)
3. take another view with equal frame to scroll view and set 0
   constrain    to    default four constraint type i.e TOP Bottom
   trailing leading.
4. Also give equal height and width to base view constraint.
5. Now try to add a button just above bottom on 2nd view
6. give following
   constrain    to button : Horizontally center, width , height ,
   bottom.
7. Try to run on simulator You should be able to scroll till button.

Comment: if I use     self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 700); within viewDidLayoutSubviews, its getting scrolled but is it possible to mention this from storyboard?

Comment: Yeas it works only if we set the content size. This saved me :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you set ScrollView contentSize ?
Please check you have set scrollable height.

Eg.

```
 scrlVIewSignUp.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, 1000)
```

Where 1000 is the approximate height.(please set height as per your requirement)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running into issues with the contentSize.
Check out [this](http://www.edwardhuynh.com/blog/2013/11/13/uiscrollview-contentsize-and-autolayout-gotcha/).it is about how to handle the contentSize when using a "pure" AutoLayout approach. The gist of it is that your constraints implicitly define the content size. You NEVER set it explicitly when using AutoLayout.

it also have, attached example project at the end of the blog post to demonstrate how it works.

Comment: if I use self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 700); within viewDidLayoutSubviews, its getting scrolled but is it possible to mention this from storyboard?